# How do I assign a material to specific faces instead of every face?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, interface

I'm trying to assign a material to faces I've selected in Edit mode. To my knowledge, it's supposed to work this way:

1. Select the faces
2. Switch to material tab
3. Select desired material in list of materials
4. Click "assign" to assign the materials to the selected faces

However, when I select the material I want to assign to the faces, it automatically assigns it to *every* face on the object. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Although Blender shows objects as having a white default surface even without any material on them, as soon as you give them a material this becomes the default material for all faces. And in this case it's not possible to assign this single material to a selection of faces and let the others be "blank", without any material. So in order to have some faces with a different material than others, you need at least two materials on your object. See Marty's answer for an example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your technique is correct as far as it goes, but there's a bit more to it.  Here is a screenshot of the material slots for a monkey:

[image: Material slots screenshot]

I've placed a material called "base material" in the first slot, (numbered zero.)  I've placed another called "assignable material" in the second slot, (numbered one.)  By default, *every* face on the material is assigned to the material in slot 0.  In order to assign materials to faces, there must be a different material in at least one of the other slots.  So, if you select slot 1 in my example, you can use your process to assign faces to it.

You can then change your mind about specific faces and assign them back to slot 0, of course.

Comment: It worked when I came back to it today. I'm not sure exactly what the problem was, but it is working now. The thing that was happening was that when I clicked on the second material, it set every face to that material before I could click "Assign".

Comment: @3QuartersColon it sounds like you ran into a bug.  I'm glad it was temporary.